# Question about problem 14-6 from Spivak's Calculus: Finding all continuous functions $f$ satisfying $\int_0^x f = (f(x))^2 + C$ for $C \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Find all continuous functions $f$ satisfying $$F(x) = \int_0^x f = (f(x))^2 + C \quad\text{for } C \neq 0,$$ assuming $f$ has at most one zero.

---

Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, by the FTC, $F$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $F'(x) = f(x) = 2f(x)f'(x)$. Now, Spivak states that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ whenever $f(x) \neq 0$, but I don't see how $f$ can ever not be differentiable, recalling that $F$ must be differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer But $f'$ would have to be well-defined anyway, that's my point

Comment: Take $f(x)=|x|$. Then $f$ is not differentiable, but $f^2$ is.

Comment: @EthanDlugie Is this a good argument: $f^2$ is diff everywhere, so $f^2$ is diff at $f(x)$, and so $f$ must be diff at $x$. If that is the case, then $f = 2ff'$ and so $f(2f' - 1) = 0$ so $f = 0$ or $f' = \frac12$, which means that $f' = \frac12$ whenever $f \neq 0$.

Is this enough to conclude that $f$ is differentiable $x$ for which $f(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Let $f(x) = |x|$. Then, $f^2$ is differentiable at $0 = f(0)$. However, this doesn't mean that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Indeed, it isn't.

Comment: @Abhi What are you replying to?

Comment: Your proposed argument.

Comment: @Abhi But my proposed argument assumes that $f \neq 0$.

Comment: Right, but I don't see why $f^2$ being differentiable at $f(x)$ implies that $f$ has to be differentiable at $x$. Could you expand on that more?

Comment: @Abhi Because we're assuming that $f^2$ is diff everywhere, so taking the derivative of $f^2$, we get that $2ff'$, which implies $f$ has to be differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Right but as it stands, you only know that $f$ is continuous right off the bat. You don't actually know if $f$ is differentiable. You can't say that $(f^2)' = 2ff'$ without already knowing that $f'$ exists.

Comment: @Abhi That's true, but $f^2$ is differentiable, so we take the derivative of $f^2$ to find that we require $f$ to be differentiable at $x$ by the chain rule. What else can we do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138002/discussion-between-abhi-and-polite-proofs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is actually extremely nice. You have to work a little bit to get to an answer, though. So, we have that:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = h'(x)$$
where $x \mapsto h(x) = (f(x))^2$. This implies that $h'$ is continuous. So, if $f(x) > 0$ at a given point $x$, $h'(x) > 0$. Since $h'$ is continuous, it follows that there is an open interval around $x$ on which $h'(x) > 0$.

Okay, let's also make another note; if $f$ is not zero at any point, then $f$ has to either be positive or it has to be negative. If there was a point $x$ where it was positive and a point $y$ where it was negative, then we could find a point $z$ where it would be zero by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Let's suppose that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a zero of $f$. So, $f(a) = 0$. Then, $f$ is non-zero on the interval $(a,\infty)$. Let's assume that $f > 0$ on the interval $(a,\infty)$. This means that $h' > 0$ on this interval. So, $f^2$ is an increasing function. Moreover, since $f(a) = 0$, it follows that $f$ is strictly positive on $(a,\infty)$. Hence, we can write:
$$f = |f| = \sqrt{f^2}$$
This is a composition of differentiable functions on $(a,\infty)$. So, $f$ is differentiable on $(a,\infty)$. Then, we can write that:
$$h' = 2ff' = f$$
Since $f$ is strictly positive on $(a,\infty)$, it follows that $f' = \frac{1}{2}$
on this interval. So, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x + k$. Now, $f$ must be continuous at $a$. It follows that $k = -\frac{1}{2}a$. So:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-a)$$
Okay, that's cool. Observe that $F(0) = (f(0))^2+ C = 0$. If $f(0) = 0$, then $C = 0$ and that's impossible. So, $C < 0$. Now, the point here is that no matter which cases we consider, every case is just about proving that $f$ is differentiable in the set $(-\infty,a) \cup (a,\infty)$. In each case, the fact that $f \neq 0$ just implies that $f' = \frac{1}{2}$ on the union I wrote above. Now, it follows that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-a)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, by continuity.

The final step is to try and find $a$. We'll just plug this into the integral equality. We get:
$$\frac{1}{4}(x-a)^2 +C = \frac{1}{4}(x-a)^2-\frac{1}{4}a^2$$

which implies that $a^2 = -4C$. So, we could pick $a = \sqrt{-4C}$ or $a = -\sqrt{-4C}$. This gives two functions that satisfy the given equality so we are done.

Comment: $h' = f$ and $f$ is being assumed to be continuous. So, $h'$ is continuous.